# Fetching last inserted ID and using it as a parameter with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm very new to PHP, trying to figure things out.

I have the following php code:

```
$read_more = '<a href="http://www.example.com/index.php?id=' . mysqli_insert_id($conn)  . '" target="_self">[read more]</a>';

$sql = "INSERT INTO database (date, headline, article, read_more) VALUES ('$_POST[date]', '$_POST[headline]', '$_POST[article]', '$read_more')";
```

The code is returning "http://www.example.com/index.php?id=0". Note that the "id" parameter is returning "0". My goal is to make it return the latest ID from the database, which is set to auto increment.

I've tried many things but nothing worked for me so far. Thanks!

EDIT: After hours of trial and error, this is how I was able to solve this problem:

```
//After connecting to the database

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (date, headline, article, read_more) VALUES ('$_POST[date]', '$_POST[headline]', '$_POST[article]', '$read_more')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

Now the latest id is saved into a variable that I can use.

Comment: You can get last ID only AFTER you insert something in current session (connection - probably one page request in php from your viewpoint). If you call it before, it does not remember anything and returns 0. If you want latest (biggest) ID existing in the table, you have to query the table: "SELECT max(ID) FROM table"

Comment: I've tried calling the mysqli_insert_id() function after the insert statement, but then the "read_more" field didn't get populated at all. I should also clarify that the connection to the database is happening in the same page as this code. This is the php script that the form calls after the user hits submit.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead. Check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) here.

```
// insert a datarow, primary key is auto_increment
// value is a unique key
$query = "INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES ('test')";
mysql_query( $query );

echo 'LAST_INSERT_ID: ',
      mysql_query( "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()" ),
      '<br>mysql_insert_id: ',
      mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: I can't make that code work. The php script doesn't even send any data to the database now.

Comment: :-D did you change the code structure that i gave you?.. can u show me your new code?

Comment: I just added your code in place of the first line of my code, right before the insert statement. I changed just the $msg variable and used $read_more instead. I'm sorry, I don't know how to paste code properly as a comment here :/

Comment: o_O u shouldn't use the whole code i provided... u should change some of it aside from the $msg.. your $mysqli_insert_id should contain your sql query..

Comment: I assumed that "DB" and "table" where meant to be changed to contain my query, but I don't know what to do with the "InsertRecord" part.

Comment: try the new one i provided you... that should be simple one.

Comment: This is what I get now: 

LAST_INSERT_ID: Resource id #9
mysql_insert_id: 0